# ASP.NET Radio Button Horizontal Direction, how to remove space between items

Tags: html, css, asp.net, web-applications

I have the following radio button:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoBtn" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdoBtn_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass ="rdoBtnItemSpacing">
<asp:ListItem Text="Regular" Value="False" Selected="True" >
</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Special" Value="True"></asp:ListItem></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

When I run the application the Items are spaced really far apart, I guess since the row is really wide. How can I keep the items fairly close together, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO please add here the rendered markup of your html including the container and the CSS you already have. That's equal to = *enough code to reproduce the problem*

Comment: The CSS is class is completely empty, I created it in case someone offers a CSS solution. What do you mean by the rendered markup? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found that first you should make the

```
RepeatLayout ="Flow"
```

and in the CSS class

```
.rdoBtnItemSpacing label{

       margin-right:30px; 
}
```

This post helped me out:
[http://forums.asp.net/t/1364321.aspx?RadioButtonList+control+space+between+buttons](http://forums.asp.net/t/1364321.aspx?RadioButtonList%20control%20space%20between%20buttons)